# D3.extent issues with month value confusion over first and last day of month

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a Plunkr for my issue, found [at the link](http://plnkr.co/edit/KxrMU9dyzeHVuBGqtCDS?p=preview)

I am having a problem with scaling when using month values. I am sure this is a simple fix.

A visualization of my issue is below (look at December):

[image]

In short, when using d3.extent in an update pattern for the axis and the bars, d3 is not computing the domain correctly. It seems to think it is less than it is and so I have one entry too many, leading one bar to hang off and the x axis to be one value too long.

My xScale is computed normally:

```
xScale = d3.time.scale()
                .domain(d3.extent(data,function(d){return d.funded_month}))
                .rangeRound([0, (w + offsetBar) - (marginleft + marginright)]);
```

Both the x Axis, bars and text are all working off the same domain.

When visualizing all years, the viz appears correctly:

[image]

Is the issue that the number of values in each respective visualization are different (13 years vs 12 months? What is the mistake?

Comment: How are you computing the extent?  The date "December 2013" is stored as midnight, December 1, 2013, so a domain from January-December 2013 would only be 11 months long, not 12, and that is being reflected in your graph.  If you want it to be inclusive of the final date in your extent, you'll need to round up to the end of the month.  Check out the [time interval functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals).

Comment: It looks like there is not an option for rounding up -- it just automatically rounds up or down. The issue is discussed here: http://grokbase.com/p/gg/d3-js/134aeyv56b/time-scale-always-forcibly-display-first-date-of-a-month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to implement an easy solution with existing libraries.

Because D3 interprets the "Month, Year" format assuming the day is the first of the month at midnight, January to December is considered only 11 months.

So I stepped the days of every month to create a smooth axis:

```
2001-01-01,68991364
2001-02-04,554541108
2001-03-07,151123291
2001-04-10,283000000
2001-05-12,8093737
2001-06-15,55718802
2001-07-18,95060100
2001-08-21,78000000
2001-09-23,150000000
2001-10-25,193330000
2001-11-28,59948530
2001-12-31,142424927
```

I was able to use an x translate on my axis text to move in sync with the bars.

Mike Bostock [goes further into this issue here.](http://grokbase.com/p/gg/d3-js/134aeyv56b/time-scale-always-forcibly-display-first-date-of-a-month)